# Laravel Relation based on JSON

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I have read the posts/answers on using a json array for a relation but being new to this platform I am struggling to get a piece working. Looking for some input.

I have models/classes/tables for Users and Services

User Table:

```
------------------------------
id | name      | serviceProvided_id
------------------------------
 1   User1       1
 2   User2       2
```

Service Table:

```
--------------------------
id |    name         |  icon
--------------------------
 1  Service1           1.jpg
 2  Service2           2.jpg
 3  Service3           3.jpg
 4  Service4           4.jpg
 5  Service5           5.jpg
```

User Model

```
    public function serviceProvided()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Service::class,'serviceProvided_id','id');
    }
```

When I get a user from the UserController i can return the relation for Service with it:

```
User::with('serviceProvided')
```

Works perfectly. What I would like to do now is make the servicesProvided be more than one value and still be able to load all of them with the User.

I was thinking the User table would then look something like this:

```
------------------------------
id | name      | serviceProvided_id
------------------------------
 1   User1       [1,2,3]
 2   User2       [1,3,5]
```

I read about a package from Jonas S (https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-json-relations) but what I keep getting stuck at is it seems like in that package it doesnt expect a dedicated column, but some other column that has key/values in it? I am getting confused and would appreciate any help i can get.

Thanks,
Jay

Comment: You need a pivot table for n:n relationships

Comment: Yep, create a pivot table and define a many to many relationship. Take a look at the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: Ok. So if i have 7 or 8 other models that are not listed here at all make a reference (or several references) to the Services table.. is it still the best approach for me to create all of those extra pivot tables?

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to make belongsToMany Relationship as you already suggested. But still if you want to acchieve from your method then you can do like these

```
$user=User::find(1);
foreach($user->serviceProvided_id as $service)
{
$services[]=$service->serviceProvided->name;
}
dd($services);
```